# Fedora change disk then install error and which solution is faster?

Tags: linux, raid, fedora, mdadm

1. I use fedora and mdadm(2hdd create to raid1), but if I change one disk then on fedora install program not work have error message. I use `"sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdb"` create `sdb` of space and I ran as follows.

> mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1
>
> cat /proc/mdstat is ok

But Fedora install program show error message and not continue to install system to RAID

2. If I use `mdadm` to create Raid6, it will get more slower than run on raid1？(hardware raid card get more faster than software raid? (I use AMD-1800X))

Comment: RAID6 is generally slower to write but faster to read then RAID1. Hardware RAID - particularly RAID6 would be faster if the controller is any good.

Comment: raid6 write get more slower than raid 1?

Comment: Yes, The double parity calculations and parellell writes to many drives simultaneously - when done in software - are "expensive". http://louwrentius.com/benchmark-results-of-random-io-performance-of-different-raid-levels.html shows software RAID0 and RAID6 have comparable read speeds but RAID6 is dramatically worse (but in a slightly contrived scenario - no caching, no block size tuning)